# "grouped error distribution"?

Tags: terminology, history

I can't figure out the meaning of emphasized phrase in the following:

> Representing a *grouped error distribution* by a multinomial distribution, Simpson (1756), Langrange (1776), and Laplace (1776) used the classical methods for deriving the distribution of the mean rectangularly and triangularly distributed errors.

I think I know what the author means by an "error distribution", but I can't figure out what the "grouped" refers to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source of the quotation would do no harm, but a guess at what is meant is possible.

We might now say *binned* or *classed*, the second term being older than the first, but the first seemingly becoming more common than the first.

Something like a distribution with classes starting at -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, or -0.5, -0.4, ..., 0.4, 0.5, or whatever the values were, seems implied.

Reporting entire data sets was uncommon in the 18th century and still rare now except for very small data sets.

In short, groups here means bins or classes.